# fetch contents from google drive dynamically

Tags: php, google-drive-api, dropbox-api

I am making a website in which I am fetching contents from dropbox and google drive.
I have got the api for dropbox :

```
<?php

/* Please supply your own consumer key and consumer secret */
$consumerKey = '';
$consumerSecret = '';

include 'Dropbox/autoload.php';

session_start();
$oauth = new Dropbox_OAuth_PHP($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);

// If the PHP OAuth extension is not available, you can try
// PEAR's HTTP_OAUTH instead.
// $oauth = new Dropbox_OAuth_PEAR($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);

$dropbox = new Dropbox_API($oauth);
?>
```

but I have not got the api for GOOGLE DRIVE in php.
Please help me through this so that I can get the API of google drive in php and with the help of which I can fetch the contents of google drive stored by a user.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Go to google.com, type in "google drive php". FIRST RESULT.

Comment: this may help you : https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive does have an API. See: [What Can You Do with the Drive Platform?](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk)

A quickstart to get it to work with PHP: [Quickstart: Run a Drive App in PHP](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php). It includes several code samples.

Comment: this has not got the code with the help of which I can display the contents of google drive on my self-created website?